# Trying to understand "or" operator inside lambda

Tags: python

I came across following code while solving [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/68978/generate-the-abacaba-sequence) problem:

```
f=lambda n:"a"[n:]or f(n-1)+chr(97+n)+f(n-1)
```

The function generates abacaba sequence of specific depth n

For example:

n = 2, output: 'abacaba'

n = 3, output: 'abacabadabacaba'

The question is, **how** does the code work? Namely, how does "or" operator work inside lambda? (I assume code above uses recursion, and to my knowledge, normally we use loops for recursion, but I don't see anything that resembles loops in the code above)

Comment: I think that the `or` is used to terminate the recursion.

Comment: `or` is lazy - if left side gives `True` then there is no need to run right side because `True or anything` always gives `True`. This way it returns result from left side if it can be converted to `True` or it returns result from right side if left side gives `False`. In similar way ca be used **and**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works the same way it does anywhere else. If the left-hand argument of `or` is truthy, the expression evaluates to that; otherwise, it evaluates to the right-hand argument. In this case, `"a"[n:]` is the empty string when `n > 0`, so it's equivalent to

```
def f(n):
    if n == 0:
        return "a"
    else:
        return f(n-1) + chr(97+n) + f(n-1)
```

Comment: Why did he put [n:] after a? I mean, why would this version: f=lambda n:"a" or f(n-1)+chr(97+n)+f(n-1) not work properly?

Comment: @Nelver: *In this case, `"a"[n:]` is the empty string when `n > 0`*. It returns the right side of the `or` when `n > 0`, and then when `n == 0` it produces `"a"` and the right side doesn’t run.

Comment: @Ry-♦ So If I get this correctly, empty string evaluates to False?

Comment: @Nelver: Yep. Try `bool("")`. Lots of other types override `__bool__`, too; for example, the number zero and empty lists/dicts/sets are all falsy.

Answer (score 0):

Let's break it down.

```
f = lambda # declare a variable f that is a function
n:         # that takes an int parameter 'n'
"a"[n:]    # if n is 0 return 'a'
or         # else
f(n-1)     # return a recursive call at n - 1
+          # plus
chr(97+n)  # character from code 97 + n
+          # plus
f(n-1)     # another recursive call
```